# Blender 2.77 - how to have my default workspace always with top, left, right, perspective like 3D studio max?

Tags: python, modeling, 3d-view, camera, customization

I am new in Blender 2.77, when i open it, i always get one view point "User Persp" how can i see at once left, top, right and perspective views? (like in 3d Studio max there is 4 view point in one GUI)

[image]

Comment: but it's not possible to check if the current view is quad view or not. how do you check if it is quad view in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> while your mouse cursor is over the **3D Viewport** to `Toggle Quad View`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to save the current blend file as the default one whenever you start Blender.

The **Toggle Quad View** function is also accessible from Blender's Python interface with the operator `bpy.ops.screen.region_quadview()` or from the Display Panel on the Tool Shelf:

[image: Toggle Quad View button on the Tool Shelf]

Please note that after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> whatever changes you have made (no matter how small) to the current blend file will become startup defaults.

Answer (score 3):

View > Toggle Quad View is similar to this. Once you have it the way you want it,  File > Save Startup File will make it that way every time you start Blender (including scene objects).

Answer (score 2):

Toggle *Quad View* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, then save this screen setup as your startup file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: How do you check if the view is quad view using python?